# After installing Windows 7, there're lines on the screen

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I've just installed Windows 7 on my Dell machine. Everything works fine except that there are one or two lines on the screen. The line is so random and I am sure that it's now the monitor problem. The graphic card is NVidia GeForce 7600. I replaced the default driver with the driver from the manufacturer and it didn't help.

When I change screen setting, the line goes away for a while and it comes back in different location. Sometimes an app window has the line and if I move the window the line follows with the window.

What can I do to fix it?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: The lines are always horizontal. And I've already tried to change refresh rates.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that an older card cannot work correctly with the very demanding Windows 7.

Some suggestions:

- If Aero is on, I would suggest turning it off.
- If you have the Sidebar, turn it off
- Look for a video driver among the optional Windows Update downloads

If all fails, this [thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/19203-huge-problem-geforce-7900-gt-horizontal-lines.html) discusses all sort of solutions, going from overclocking the video card to flashing its firmware.

But I would first try another and newer video card, to see if this would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

harrymc is probably correct but,

try changing the monitor resolution (not just the refresh rates) to see if the lines go away at lower or higher resolutions - if they do its your graphics card - get a new one